error 404 apache debian laravel
Hola amigos estoy trabajando con laravel, pero cuando defino mis rutas me retorna un error
del server del tipo 404, pero en este caso no es el 404 de laravel si no del servidor
por defecto de debian apache. Uso laravel en su version 11. Reinicie el servidor y borra la cache del navegador y tampoco funciono.

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/blog', function(){
 return 'hello';
});

eh buscado respuestas similares pero no encontre una que sea parecido al mio, incluso cree una vista para ver si era eso, y tampoco lo toma :,v . podrian darme alguna sugerencias?. Gracias
Ya lo resolvi xD solo tenia que agregar en el archivo de apache.conf la ruta e indexarlo.
<Directory /var/www/html/myFirtLaravelApp/public>
 AllowOverride All
 allow from all
 Options +Indexes
</Directory>

y ya jalowin


para resolverlo solo se agrega en la configuracion del servidor apache.conf el directorio con el que se esta trabajando.
  <Directory /var/www/html/myFirtLaravelApp/public>
   AllowOverride All
   allow from all
   Options +Indexes
 </Directory>

y eso es todo.
